# geopandas plotting - Identify locations that fall outside of the map

Tags: plot, gis, shapes, shapefile, geopandas

I have a `shapefile` that shows the map of Pakistan at district level. I also have a `geodataframe` that has information about polling stations in Pakistan.

I have mapped the `geodataframe` on to the `shapefile`, but noticed that some lat/lon values from the `geodataframe` are wrong i.e. they lie outside Pakistan.

I want to identify which polling stations these are. (I want to select those rows from the `geodataframe`) Is there a way to do this?

Please see below for reference - the black dots indicate polling stations, and the colourful map is the map of Pakistan at district levels:

[image_pakistan_map_pollingstations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKPlf.png)

edit:

So I'm trying this and it seems to work, however it's taking a very long time to run (been running it for 5+ hrs now) - for reference, the geodataframe has about 50,000 rows and it's called ours_NA_gdf.

```
for i in range(len(ours_NA_gdf)):
    if ours_NA_gdf['geometry'][i].within(pakistan['geometry'][0]):
        ours_NA_gdf.at[i, 'loc_validity'] = 'T'
    else:
        ours_NA_gdf.at[i, 'loc_validity'] = 'F'

ours_NA_gdf[ours_NA_gdf['loc_validity']=='F']
```

Comment: You haven't provided this question with any reproducible data.  It's quite impossible to answer your question with any assurance of accuracy - based on the limited information you supplied.  Many questions like this get voted the dreaded down button ( -1 ),  but you did provide information showing you worked some on this problem.

Comment: I thought the question was quite straightforward, I am simply curious if there is a way to identify / trace back which rows from the geodataframe are lying outside of Pakistan in the map.

Comment: Simple feature objects or spatial objects?

Comment: Would you be able to have a look at my edited post? thank you!

Comment: If you provide the source of your data for the polling sites, then I can probably assist you with this question.

Comment: @dmswjd Have you checked my answer? Any comment or further question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the geometries of Pakistan you use are the problem. They are too complex and detailed to use. In your use-case, simple geometry provided by `naturalearth_lowres` should give better performance. Here I provide a runnable code that demonstrates the use of simple Pakistan geometry to perform `contains()` operations, and assign properties `color` of points to plot on the map.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

# create a geoDataFrame of points locations across Pakistan areas
pp = 40
lons = np.linspace(60, 80, pp)
lats = np.linspace(22, 39, pp)

# create point geometry
# points will be plotted across Pakistan in red (outside) and green (inside)
points = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(lons, lats)]
# create a dataframe of 3 columns
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'longitude': lons, 'latitude': lats, 'point': points})
# manipulate dataframe geometry
gdf = mydf.drop(['longitude', 'latitude'], axis=1)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=gdf.point)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,7), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
parki = world[(world.name == "Pakistan")]  #take a country of interest

# grab the geometry of Pakistan
# can .simplify() it if need be
pg = parki['geometry']

newcol = []
for index, row in gdf.iterrows(): # Looping over all points
    res = pg.contains( row.geometry).values[0]
    newcol.append(res)

# add a new column ('insideQ') to the geodataframe
gdf['insideQ'] = newcol
# add a new column ('color') to the geodataframe
gdf.loc[:, 'color'] = 'green'  #set color='green'
# this set color='red' to selected rows
gdf.loc[gdf['insideQ']==False, 'color'] = 'red'

# plot Pakistan
ax.add_geometries(parki['geometry'], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='lightpink', label='Pakistan')

# plot all points features of `gdf`
gdf.plot(ax=ax, zorder=20, color=gdf.color)

ax.set_extent([60, 80, 22, 39])  #zoomed-in to Pakistan

LegendElement = [
                 mpatches.Patch(color='lightpink', label='Pakistan')
                ]
ax.legend(handles = LegendElement, loc='best')

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]